# how to update date field in a record to null?

Tags: mysql, date-format, date

I have  records in a table which a field named as 'validity' contains date as '8/15/1947 12:00:00 AM'. I need to set this date as null. I am having 1000 records,in that validity field is '8/15/1947 12:00:00 AM'. I wrote a syntax

```
update ACCESSCODE set VALIDITY=null where VALIDITY='8/15/1947 12:00:00 AM';
```

which throws error as:

> 'Incorrect date value: '8/15/1947 12:00:00 AM' for column 'VALIDITY' at row 1'.

Here is my table skeleton.

```
CREATE TABLE `ACCESSCODE` 
(  `SNO` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
   `ACCESS_CODE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,   
   `STATUS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `VALIDITY` date DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`SNO`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM 
  AUTO_INCREMENT=10103
  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

Please advice and correct me with the syntax.My table name is ACCESSCODE. Am working this TOAD. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the suggested in the manuals format for datetime literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the suggested formats in MySQL documentation, for **[datetime literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html)**, like the `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format:

```
WHERE validity = '1947-05-18 00:00:00' ;
```

or the simpler (in this case, that there is no time part):

```
WHERE validity = '1947-05-18' ;
```

Comment: its not working same error occurs. Sorry.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column? Can you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE  ACCESSCODE;` in the question?

Comment: I have added datatypes of ACCESSCODE table

Comment: and `WHERE validity = '1947-05-18'` throws this error? Seems unlikely.

Comment: yes. If I put `update ACCESSCODE set VALIDITY=null where VALIDITY='08-15-1947';` it throws `1292: Incorrect date value: '08-15-1947' for column 'VALIDITY' at row 1` . Is there any thing wrong?